# How to get watermark stored in AAC audio in C++

Tags: c++, watermark, aac

I am working on design of a C++ application which will read packets(188 bytes each) from stream file(.ts) and extract watermark from AAC audio. I am able to read the file using fread(), process each packet and identify if the packet is AAC audio by checking stream type(0x0F)and add them in to frame buffer. 
Can anyone please help me to proceed further? I don't know exactly the logic of extracting watermark from AAC. I am working in c++/windows/linux.Is there any sourcecode available? Thanks in advance.